# How to maintain a dynamic page title with valid markup?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Currently in my code I have something like this outside of the HTML head tag:

`<title>My Website - <?php echo $row['title']; ?></title>`

This works but does not validate with w3 because with XHTML titles can only be modified within the HTML head tag.

How does one solve this? I want to maintain 100% valid XHTML Strict markup which I currently have but I don't want to use any messy hacks either. I read that changing the website title with Javascript after the page loads is bad practice but it seems like the only viable option here. What does SO think?

Comment: Why don't you just put that inside the `<head>` tag?

Comment: Is there an reason that you put the `<title>` **outside** the `<head>`?

Comment: php returns the value of $row['title'] right ? this wont cause any validation errors..

Comment: The reason why I put it outside of head was because $row didn't exist until the body. I suppose I could just move the database calls to outside of all the html.. Doh. I need some sleep. Thanks guys >.<

Comment: You should **definitely** move the database calls outside the template. You are mixing presentation logic with model logic, which is only going to cause major headaches.

Comment: @Andrea: I mostly do except for comments. Is this ok? The only other option I see is loading all the comments in to an array outside of the template but even then I am mixing some model logic with presentation logic when looping through the array. Also it would most likely be slower.

Comment: Looping through an array is presentation logic. If you have to print the entries of the array somewhere, you will need to be able to get these entries one at a time. But you said you started your html template before even doing the database calls, which is entirely another matter. As for speed, there are other options that you will want to consider, like PHP accelerators, caching, in-RAM-database, PHP compilation and so on according to the complexity of your site and the number of your visitors. An extra loop is not going to hurt, unless you run Facebook. And even in that case, I'm pretty...

Comment: ...sure that they have separated their database calls from the templates. I think you are just doing premature optimization, By the way, I do not even see a reason why there should be an extra loop. You can just pass to the view whatever is that your database spits out, and loop through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should validate correctly if you paste in the HTML(in the validator) that is rendered after the PHP is done executing (assuming you put the title tag in the right position[aka in the `<head></head>` tags])